# Грамматические основы (в зависимости от структуры предложений)

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, основа

Будут ли различаться грамматические основы в этих предложениях?

*Есть такие люди. — Такие люди есть.

Нет таких людей. — Таких людей нет.*

Comment: Роман, если Вы посчитаете мою правку неточной, то можете ее откатить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(1) Есть такие люди. — Такие люди есть.
(2) Нет таких людей. — Таких людей нет.***

Грамматические основы этих предложений **не различаются**, это предложения с инверсией. Предложения (1) **двусоставные**, а предложения (2) **безличные односоставные**.

Инверсия сказуемого в этом случае не меняет структуру предложения, вынесение сказуемого в начало предложения делается с целью его актуализации (логического выделения).

Проблемы с определением структуры предложения  возникают, если **при инверсии возможны** **варианты,** а это происходит только в некоторых случаях, например:

1) **В безличных предложениях с количественной оценкой**: *Снега (было) много. — Много снега.* В разных ситуациях это может быть безличное предложение (семантический субъект выражен сущ. в  Р.п.) или назывным предложением (именная часть выражена сочетанием).

2) Также **варианты возможны**, если **сказуемое и подлежащее выражены сущ. в И.п**., например: *Москва — столица России. Славные люди соседи мои.* При тождестве (в первом случае) инверсия изменяет грамматический статус слова, подлежащее и сказуемое меняются местами,  а при оценке (во втором случае) происходит инверсия сказуемого.

3) Довольно сложно разобраться с главными членами, если в предложении есть **инфинитив,** который может быть подлежащим, а может входить в состав сказуемого, например: *Бегать по утрам полезно* (полезная привычка, двусоставное предложение, бегать — подлежащее). *Ему было бы полезно бегать по утрам* (безличное предложение, модальная связка выражена наречием, инфинитив входит в состав сказуемого (СГС), субъект действия выражен сущ. в Т.п.).